# How can i design a list of images in PSCollectionView with different Heights?

Tags: ios

Iam new to ios development.I confused to design like a screen which i attached here.
Please help me if anyone know how to design like this.Iam not yet started to design the screen.

Thanks in Advance....![design like this screen][1]

Comment: which part are you stuck on?

Comment: actually we design tableview list with cell right?
but here the screen is looking like 2 images sidebyside and with different heights.

so i don't know how to design like this.....

Answer (score 1):

this is [WaterfallCollectionView](https://github.com/SureCase/WaterfallCollectionView) sample code as per your requirement

Comment: Thanks For your Answer.When iam using this to load images nothing is displaying can you help me to load like images.

Comment: can you  paste code then i can help you ,you can use sdwebimage or Afnetworking for load image

Comment: In sample they placed label right.Instead of that label we have to show images.So i taken imageview in place of label.

Comment: you want to disaply static image

Comment: Dynamic images i need to display